# ngFor cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular

I have these interfaces

**order.interface.ts**

```js
export interface Order {
    userName: string;
    food: Food[];
    description: string;
    totalPrice: number;
    deliveryAddress: string;
}
```

**food.interface.ts**

```js
export interface Food {
    description: string;
    price?: number;
}
```

I create an array of objects to then go through it in html

```js
 orders: Order[] = [
    {
      userName:  "Miguel",
      totalPrice: 90,
      description: "ice cream",
      deliveryAddress: "address",
      food: [
        {
          description: 'food1',
        },
        {
          description: 'food2',
        }
      ]
    }]
```

```html
<ion-list ngFor="let item of order?.food;">
    <ion-item>
      {{item.description}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

i get the following error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'description')
```

Comment: How are you looping through `orders` to get `order`? Update the question with HTML/template which loops `ngFor=let order of orders`. Better: Add stackblitz link

Comment: I Couldn't play it on stackblitz. I finally solved the error, I had to import CommonModule in component since it didn't recognize ngFor. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At some point your `item` is being `undefined` thus not having a `description` attribute.

Try conditionally accessing attribute with `?.`:

```js
{{item?.description}}
```